# Flutter: firebase_auth null object reference error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, mobile, dart, flutter

I am developing a Flutter app which uses firebase_auth and firebase_database plugins, everything worked until recently it failed with the following error:

```
E/StorageHelpers(16377): Failed to turn object into JSON
E/StorageHelpers(16377): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzi(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzg(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzbq.zzaa(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zzal(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdb.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzci.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
E/StorageHelpers(16377):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
W/Binder  (16377): Binder call failed.
```

I just got no idea and this problem has been blocking my development progress for a while, it happens on my Android device (LG V20) and emulator. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the output from Flutter Doctor command:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.11.6 15G19009, locale en)
    • Flutter version 0.4.4 at /Volumes/OSX_DATA/Users/jimmy/documents/development/FLutter/flutter
    • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (5 weeks ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/OSX_DATA/Users/jimmy/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK at /Volumes/OSX_DATA/Users/jimmy/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0-rc2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Volumes/OSX_DATA/Users/jimmy/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 8.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 8.2.1, Build version 8C1002
    ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 9.0.0.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    ! CocoaPods out of date (1.5.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.io/platform-plugins
      To upgrade:
        brew upgrade cocoapods
        pod setup

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4892.1

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • LG H990 • LGH9904548262d • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)
```

The iOS issue should have no concern here.

I am using Dark SDK 1.24.3, and the Firebase plugins version are as follow:

```
firebase_analytics: ^1.0.1                                      
firebase_auth: ^0.5.11                                          
firebase_database: ^1.0.1                                       
firebase_storage: ^0.3.7                                        
firebase_admob: ^0.5.5
```

Thanks and Regards,

Jimmy

Comment: I'd try `flutter channel dev` and `flutter channel master`

Comment: None of the channels works for me :(

Comment: I had the same error a while ago, don't know what exactly fixed it.

Comment: Anybody out there can give me a hand? This is really frustrating.